# MySQL - Stored Function SET SELECT INTO returning Error 1366 in VIEW

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

*Note - I have edited to better reflect the complexity on the math. Sorry, very new to this.*

I am trying to repeatedly run a mathematical function on certain metrics in a dataset in MySQL. The mathematical lag function involves several variables but I only need to alter one of them. The idea is to create this as a function and then call the function in a view. I am able to create the function and the view. However, when I call the view I receive

``` Error Code: 1366. Incorrect decimal value: 'Variable' for column ``.``.`metric` at row 280 ```

Normally this would just indicate bad data entry from the original table. But here's the catch - the table only has 279 observations. Why is my function trying to interpret nonexistent rows?
I've tried pulling out just the select function and it works fine so it's not a problem there.

Here is the code I've used with some dummy names to preserve data integrity. The actual formula is more complicated but the same error occurs with even basic math so I've used that.

**To create the function**

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS Levels;
CREATE FUNCTION Levels(
    metric decimal(65,4),
    dataset VARCHAR(60)
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(65,4)
BEGIN
    DECLARE levels DECIMAL(65,4);
    SET levels = NULL;
    SELECT
        metric - (LAG(metric,1) OVER (PARTITION BY clown_id ORDER BY year));
    INTO levels
    FROM dataset;
    RETURN levels;
END //
```

**To create and call view**

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS Circus_Mainfile;
CREATE VIEW  Circus_Mainfile AS
SELECT
my_database.circus_inputs.*,Levels('Clowns', 'my_database.circus_inputs`) AS More_clowns
FROM my_database.circus_inputs;

SELECT * FROM Circus_Mainfile LIMIT 279;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use variables for column and table names. `metric + 2` is trying to add 2 to the string `Clowns`, not the column named `Clowns`.

Answer (score 0):

The function shouldn't select from the table, that's done by the view itself. The function should just receive the value that was selected, and perform the calculation.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Levels(prev_level DECIMAL(65, 4)) RETURNS DECIMAL(65, 4)
BEGIN
    RETURN prev_level + 2
END
```

Then you call it in the view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW Circus_Mainfile AS
SELECT i.*, 
    Levels(i.clowns) AS More_clowns
FROM my_database.circus_inputs AS i;
```

Comment: I copied this exactly and am receiving the exact same error. I have also updated the post to better reflect the complexity of the math I am using but even with +2, I receive 1366

Comment: What values do you have in the `clowns` column of the table? Please show some sample table contents.